# Google maps premium - Why - "The signature parameter is not required for the Google Maps JavaScript API"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-premium-plan

I was migrating my maps to use the premium plan and followed the instructions:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/get-api-key (these are for the static maps, but I believed same applies for other apis)

Paragraph - **Generating a digital signature to use with client IDs**

I was able to generated a digital signature for my script result in something like:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&client=clientID&channel=qa&signature=signature"></script>`

It works but I receive a warning saying that the signature is not requied and indeed it works without a signature.

Apparently I need a signature for staticmaps and directions, so why does this not apply for standard apis?

I was trying to find a full list of apis for which I need a signature and for which I don't, but to avail. Can someone give a clue, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the signature parameter for Google Maps JavaScript API because your client ID is already protected by the list of allowed URLs/domains that you can manage in the Cloud Support portal.

You can read about URLs authorization for client IDs in the following document:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#registering-authorized-urls

In case of static maps or web services (Geocoding API, Directions API, etc.) you don't have any kind of per URL protection, so you have to generate a digital signature in order to protect your client ID from unauthorized use.

For further details about authentication and authorization in Premium plan take a look at

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview#authentication-and-authorization

I hope this helps!

### Update

Premium plan for Google Maps APIs doesn't exist anymore, you should check Google Maps Platform documentation on order to address your doubts.

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I've have been thinking, although it's not clear why this same url/domain protection by referrer is not applicable for static maps or directions...

Comment: It's not applicable because you can call web service or static map from a backend server and in this case there is no reliable referrer.